# If you make a client-side getJSON() call with (&callback=) to a site that is rate-limited by IP address, do they see your site or the end-user's?

Tags: jquery, json, ip-address, jsonp, rate-limiting

If your web app uses web service API calls to an external source, some of these sources will **rate-limit you based on IP address**.

If you make these calls from **client-side JavaScript** -- meaning that they are triggered by browser actions of the end user -- **does the remote site** (which sends back the JSON data) **see your site's IP address or the IP address of the end-user** 
(for the purpose of this IP address-based rate limiting)?

My understanding is that by using **`&callback=`** in the data source URL, you will issue a **`JSONP`** request, ***which means that the address seen by the remote host is that of the end-user and not the address of your site***.

For example:

```
jQuery.getJSON(url+"&callback=?", function(data) {
    alert("Stock Symbol: " + data.symbol + ", Stock Price: " + data.price);
});
```

***Is it correct that a call like the one above would be seen as coming from the end-user's IP address and not from your web app's server IP address?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They see the end user's IP, a JSONP request goes straight from the user's browser to the URL it points to.  What you're basically doing by making a JSONP call is adding this to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="url?callback=someFunctionName"></script>
```

This makes the browser just fetch and run that script, which has this content:

```
someFunctioName({ /* data object */ });
```